# Where does the batch of data persistence to disk happen during batch execution of DML and commit phase?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, relational-database, persistence

I plan to write a program updating or importing a bunch of data in parallel in a relational database like Oracle or SQL-Server, Mysql etc.

The following is the execution code model in each parallel thread in Java:

```
statement.setAutoCommit(false);
//a batch of DML
statement.executeBatch();
statement.commit();
```

Where does the *persistence* to disk happen in the code model above? During the execution of batch of DML - `executeBatch()`, or during the commit of batch - `conn.commit()`?

Concern: implementation of both these 2 phases might already in parallel. If so there might be no big sense to implement this program in parallel as the `executeBatch()` and `commit()` might already occupy very broad I/O bandwidth.

This question might depend on the implementations among databases, but I still bet that the implementation is similar at least among those popular databases.

Comment: There is no method `commitBatch()` in the JDBC API, so your question makes no sense. You likely mean [`executeBatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch--), and there the behavior that is expected of drivers is described in the API doc (that is the batch is sent to the server when you call `executeBatch()`). Also understand that is next to impossible to generalize over all database systems, because each can do things differently depending on their implementation, which would make a corrected question too broad.

Comment: Thanks for your remind, I modified it accordingly by changing the `commitBatch()` to `executeBatch()`. But I still think the persistence implementations of those popular databases is based on the same or very similar algorithms

Comment: When you ask about "persistence to disk", are you wanting to know how the database manages persistence, or whether the JDBC driver sends the batch to the DB immediately or waits until the commit is issued?

Comment: @hugh my question is: Does the *persistence* to disk happen during `executeBatch()` or during `commit()` phase :)

Comment: That is 1) not related to JDBC itself, and 2) depending on the underlying database system, which makes it too broad. And if you want to know for a specific database system, then you're probably better off on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ . BTW: Your "concern" does not make any sense to me: Execution and commit cannot occur in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer this for Oracle SQL, but as others have pointed out, other RDBMSs may vary.

Batch processing allows several statements to be batched before being sent to the DB - this is to minimize network overhead, and isn't related to persistence.

When you call `Statement.executeBatch()`, the statements previously stored (using `addBatch()`) are sent to the database.
At this point the database will enlisted these statements in a transaction and write them to the redo log buffer.  Since you have auto-commit disabled, this will not be committed immediately.  At the point when you issue the commit, the redo log buffer is flushed to disk (in the redo log), making the transaction permanent.  However, the DB [may decide to flush the buffer sooner](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1670195800346464273) - the log writer process manages the buffer to optimise the I/O, so it's possible that by the time you issue your commit, the commit itself is all that needs to be written to disk.  The change to the actual data file is held in an in-memory cache by the DB - this can be written back to disk at a later time by a background task as it isn't critical for data integrity, and exactly when this happens will depend on other factors, including whether other users are accessing contiguous rows in the same table(s).

I should stress through all of this that RDBMSs are highly optimised systems designed to be highly parallel and scalable - if there are performance problems in this area, it's more likely to be the DBA's concern than application programmers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, that is very good to know. But I don't understand why you also mentioned that is related to persistence, and I just would like to know when the persistence happens as I think that is the main factor of the network I/O

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here - the persistence happens on the DB server when the commit is received, because that's when the redo log buffer is written to disk.  As I describe, there are a few other processes involved too, but these happen asynchronously.